# iDangerous swipe not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to put a next/prev button on my swiper and I can't get it to work I've tried various stuff and its just not working, can someone put out why its not working. I'm using jquery one not zepto.

Tried this one.

```
<span class="button-next">Next button</span>
<span class="button-prev">Previous button</span>
<script>
$(function(){
  var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper();
  $('.button-next').click(function(){mySwiper.swipeNext()})
  $('.button-prev').click(function(){mySwiper.swipePrev()})

})
</script>
```

This is how I initialise my swipe which is working fine.

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-container.newscol-swiper',{ 
         slideClass: 'post-item',
             slidesPerView: 4,
             slidesPerViewFit: false,
             loop: true,
             centeredSlides: true,
             autoplay: 5000,
             speed: 400,
             calculateHeight: true,
             roundLength: true,
             mode: 'horizontal'
             })
```

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle or a working code snippet for the same

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the following? (make sure you use the latest version of Swiper)

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 30
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

As instructed here:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/14-nav-arrows.html